# R: Finding similiar/ "duplicate" PAIRS of Text Data

Tags: r, excel, if-statement

I have 2 columns of address which are not exact duplicates , but I want to pass a code that if the first 5 characters of column 1 address matches the first 5 characters of column 2 address , then its true if not it would be false.

Here is how my data is now

### Column 1

---

2310 Aldergrove Ave

---

3901 Castle Hayne

### Column 2

2310Aldergrove

3901Castle

So for both this since the first 4 characters match I want my third columns to say True , True.

Comment: Your question is of poor quality. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, https://stackoverflow.com/help, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
data <- data.frame(col1=c("2310 Aldergrove Ave", "3901 Castle Hayne"), 
                   col2=c("2310Aldergrove", "3901Castle"))
substr(gsub(" ", "", data$col1), 1, 5) == substr(data$col2, 1, 5)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: How do i replicate the same when there are 1000 pairs of smilaiar address on a .csv file and need to do the same analysis? I would have to create a new column for TRUE/FALSE